# Merging two unordered lists of first and last names

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I'm attempting to merge two lists. One is a list of first names and the second is a list of last names. I'd like to figure out what the best approach with jQuery

I have this:

```
<ul class="first-names">
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Betty</li>
</ul>

<ul class="last-names">
    <li>Doe</li>
    <li>White</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like this:

```
<ul class="full-names">
    <li>John Doe</li>
    <li>Betty White</li>
</ul>
```

So far I've tried this and it isn't even close to working:

```
$( "ul.last-names li" ).text(function( index ) {
    $('u.first-names li').append(this).text();
});
$("ul.first-names").removeClass("first-names").addClass("full-names");
```

It ends up with:

```
<ul class="full-names">
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Doe</li>
    <li>White</li>
    <li>White</li>
    <li>Betty</li>
    <li>Doe</li>
    <li>White</li>
    <li>White</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're required to show your attempt. Post your jQuery, please.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I just edited to show my embarrassing attempt. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two lists are of equal length, you could use a function like the following that would loop through each `<ul>` element and append the names into your resulting `<ul>` :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        MergeNames();
    });

    function MergeNames(){
      // Assumes that the number of elements are equal
      var firstNames = $('.first-names li');
      var lastNames = $('.last-names li');
      // Ensure they are equal (optional)
      if(firstNames.length == lastNames.length){
        // Loop through and build your new list
        for(var i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++){
           $('.full-names').append('<li>' + $(firstNames[i]).text() + ' ' + $(lastNames[i]).text() + '</li>');
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

You can [see an example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/furicu/edit?html,output) and the resulting output below :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, assuming you want to be left with only the one list, of the full-names *and* that the relevant first-names and last-names are in order:

```
// caching the relevant last-name <li> elements, and then
// removing them from the HTML:
var lastNames = $('.last-names li').remove();

// selecting the <ul> with the class-name of 'first-names',
// using .toggleClass() to remove the classes that the
// <ul> currently has ('first-names') and adding those
// that it does not currently have ('full-names').
$('ul.first-names').toggleClass('first-names full-names')

  // finding the <li> elements in that <ul>:
  .find('li')

  // updating the text of those elements, via the anonymous
  // function of the text() method; the first argument ('i')
  // is the index of the current element in the jQuery collection
  // returned by the selector:
  .text(function(i){

    // here we trim the text content of the current Node (not
    // a jQuery object) using String.prototype.trim()
    // and concatenating that with a blank space and the
    // <li> of the equal index to the current node (here we
    // use get() to retrieve the DOM node from the cached
    // collection):
    return this.textContent.trim() + ' ' + lastNames.get( i ).textContent.trim();
});
```

```js
var lastNames = $('.last-names li').remove();

$('ul.first-names').toggleClass('first-names full-names').find('li').text(function(i) {
  return this.textContent.trim() + ' ' + lastNames.get(i).textContent.trim();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first-names">
  <li>John</li>
  <li>Betty</li>
</ul>

<ul class="last-names">
  <li>Doe</li>
  <li>White</li>
</ul>
```

To use plain JavaScript is also relatively simple, though rather more verbose:

```
// caching a reference to the last-names <ul>:
var lastNamesList = document.querySelector('ul.last-names'),

// caching references to the descendant <li> elements of the
// last-names <ul>, converting the collection to an Array,
// using Array.from():
    lastNames = Array.from( lastNamesList.querySelectorAll('li') ),

// caching the first-names <ul>:
    firstNameList = document.querySelector('ul.first-names');

// removing the 'last-names' class from the element:
firstNameList.classList.remove('last-names');

// adding the 'full-names' class-name:
firstNameList.classList.add('full-names');

// using querySelectorAll() to find the child <li> nodes of the
// first-names <ul>, and converting that collection to an Array
// in order to use the Array.prototype.forEach() method:
Array.from( firstNameList.querySelectorAll('li') ).forEach(function(li, index) {
  // in the anonymous function:
  // 'li':     a reference to the current <li> element of the
  //           array of nodes over which we're iterating,
  // 'index' : the index of the current array-element within the
  //           array over which we're iterating

  // here we update the textContent of the current <li> to a
  // combination of the trimmed current textContent, plus a
  // space plus the trimmed textContent of the <li> of the
  // same index held within the lastNames array:
  li.textContent = li.textContent.trim() + ' ' + lastNames[ index ].textContent.trim();
});

// here we find the parent of the lastNamesList node, and
// use the cached reference to remove that Node from the
// document:
lastNamesList.parentNode.removeChild(lastNamesList);
```

```js
var lastNamesList = document.querySelector('ul.last-names'),
  lastNames = Array.from(lastNamesList.querySelectorAll('li')),
  firstNameList = document.querySelector('ul.first-names');

firstNameList.classList.remove('last-names');
firstNameList.classList.add('full-names');

Array.from(firstNameList.querySelectorAll('li')).forEach(function(li, index) {
  li.textContent = li.textContent.trim() + ' ' + lastNames[index].textContent.trim();
});

lastNamesList.parentNode.removeChild(lastNamesList);
```

```html
<ul class="first-names">
  <li>John</li>
  <li>Betty</li>
</ul>

<ul class="last-names">
  <li>Doe</li>
  <li>White</li>
</ul>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
  - [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: Good detailed answer, and approach. Gonna back this one and delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please show your attempt and, if appropriate, a demo. Here's what I'd do:

```
<script>
$('#first-names li').each(function() {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    var firstName = $(this).text();
    var lastName = $('#last-names li').eq(idx).text();

    $('#full-names').append('<li>' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + '</li>');
});
</script>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gnvcbLky/)**

Notice that I've converted your selectors to IDs. I think that's appropriate here. Also, it's not clear whether you intended for the combined list to be created programmatically, and whether it should replace one of the original lists.